# UITableViewCell shows highlighted state after I call reloadSections:withRowAnimation:

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a lot of sections. Each section has a cell at its top which can be selected (taking you to a detail screen), n rows without selection after, and finally one row which can be pressed to expand/collapse the middle rows. Everything works fine, the logic to manage the number of rows and the expanded/collapse feature with the reloadSections:withRowAnimation: method using UITableViewRowAnimationFade, but my problem is that, eventually, pressing the expand/collapse row, the last one, makes the first one to be shown highlighted. This doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes, but it makes no sense because I'm not touching the first row at all.

I have to say I'm using a custom backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView for the cells. Without the last one (leaving the default blue selectedBackgroundView) the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something with reuseIdentifiers. If a cell is being reused, it could sometimes be a cell that was selected before. Does it happen when the bottom row (the one you press) is moved out of your view by the rows that appear?

Anyway, the solution should be to deselect the bottom row *before* you insert the others.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, I think this has to be something related to cell reusing. The bottom row never moves out of the view, but it could. Also, the first thing I do in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is call deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: for that row, so that doesn't solve the problem. I have to say I'm using a custom backgroundView for the cell. Without it, the problem is gone. I'm going to update the question to say this, too.

Comment: Do you set the cell as not selected in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? I'm not sure it that would interfere with anything, but it might help...

Comment: Not in cellForRow, but in Interface Builder. The first one has the default selection, the middle rows have none and the last one has also default selection. When you press the first one, the app takes you to a new screen (typical behaviour). When you press the last one, the app expands/collapses the middle rows. The last one shows its typical selected/unselected behaviour properly but also, sometimes, when you press the last one, the first one shows its selected state, too. This one is the problem I need to solve.

Comment: Just to check: do the cells have different reuseIdentifiers? Either in IB or in your code?

Comment: Yes, each type of cell (the first one, the middle rows and the last one) have different reuse indentifiers (they also have different skins and behaviours).

Comment: Ok, back to my last comment. Could you try to explicitly deselect any cell you return from cellForRowAtIndexPath? A cell might have been selected at runtime, so overriding it might help. Otherwise try doing the same in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. 

If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas, so I really hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried in several delegate methods which are called before the cell is shown with both `cell.selected = NO` and `tableView:deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` and the problem is still there. It's really annoying. Thanks, anyway.